# Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace Google Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I tried to find a solution for this error but I cannot find the right answer I checked several times my code and I did not find any typewrite error so I need some help to find what is wrong with this,
the popup window open and closed after a while then give this error
Here is the firebase file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {...};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: First of all, you need to check google auth is enabled on sign-in methods